# Making a terminal game in python and I'm having trouble with a while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, game-development

I started making this game a little while ago for a school project and I wanted to make a while loop that checks for invalid answers and asks the question again but in doing so my if statements that are supposed to give a response to the question simply won't and I'm not sure where to look.

here's what I tried but whenever I type 1 or 2 in the input the code just ends. I tried putting the if statements inside the loop but nothing changed

```
#Add while loop to accept non int answers and recall input.
while True:
    try:
        question1 = int(input("1. oui 2. non \n"))
    except ValueError:
        slow_type("essai un nombre ou de répondre la question.")
        continue
    
    else:
        break

#slow_type the following two strings if condition is met.
if question1 == "1":
    slow_type("Alors, voici mon histoire...")
    
if question1 == "2":
   slow_type("D'accord.")
```

Comment: your variable is of type `int` but you test it against `str`

Comment: @diggusbickus Thanks I changed that and now it just repeats the input again and afterwards the code ends again

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention, I think this is what you need to use:

```
while True:
    try:
        question1 = int(input("1. oui 2. non \n"))
    except ValueError:
        slow_type("essai un nombre ou de répondre la question.")
        continue
  
   #slow_type the following two strings if condition is met.
    if question1 == 1:
        slow_type("Alors, voici mon histoire...")
        
    elif question1 == 2:
       slow_type("D'accord.")
    else:
        break
```